# Why can't my rule solve for X in a simple algebraic equation?

Tags: prolog, constraint-programming

I'm new to Prolog, so please be gentle.

This is my rule:

```
solve(X) :- A = B, A is (7 * (X - 2)), B is (3 * (X + 4)).
```

Obviously, the correct answer here is `6.5`.  If I give that to Prolog, it confirms:

```
| ?- solve(6.5).

yes
```

However, if I ask Prolog to do the dirty work, it throws an error:

```
| ?- solve(X).
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

I fully concede that whatever is going on here is due to my misunderstanding of Prolog.  Can someone explain to me how I might get this to work or why it won't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a library for this, available in SWI-Prolog at least: library(clpr) and library(clpq).

Here from the top level for Reals:

```
?- use_module(library(clpr)).
true.

?- {7 * (X - 2) = 3 * (X + 4)}.
X = 6.5 ;
false.
```

Or, if you use Rationals:

```
?- use_module(library(clpq)).
true.

?- {7 * (X - 2) = 3 * (X + 4)}, R is float(X).
X = 13 rdiv 2,
R = 6.5.
```

If you want to do it yourself, it will be of course much more work. You would have to write code like

```
...,
(   ground(X)
->  7 * (X - 2) =:= 3 * (X + 4)
;   X is (3*4 + 2*7) / (7 - 3)
),
...
```

By the way, what you are doing: `A = B, A is ..., B is ...`.
This is a bit dangerous, for example:

```
?- A = B, A is 3 - 2, B is sin(pi/2).
false.

?- 3 - 2 =:=  sin(pi/2).
true.
```

`3 - 2` evaluates to the integer 1; then, `sin(pi/2)` evaluates to the floating point number 1.0, and this does not unify with the integer 1. So, the first query fails!

```
?- 1 = 1.0.
false.
```

Comment: Please consider using CLP(Q) instead of CLP(R): We cannot trust the results of CLP(R).

Answer (score 6):

In Prolog, `is` is an arithmetic evaluation operator. It calculates the result of an expression on its right side, and assigns it to a variable on its left side.

The expression to be evaluated must contain only numbers and arithmetic operators/functions. In other words, to evaluate an expression, `is` must already know all the numbers in it.

Another way of saying this is that [`is` is "unidirectional"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2), unlike the `=` which is bi-directional. Which is what you expected. And that is the meaning of the error that you got.

Solving such equations - constraints - is a job for a [constraint solver](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpqr).

Answer (score 1):

Prolog works by unification. It tries to make structures the same.

So, for example, if I try to unify `[3, X, 5]` with `[3, 4, 5]` that works fine and `X = 4`.

In your code you are first saying `A = B`. That's fine as initially `A` and `B` are not instantiated so you are basically tying their destinies to each other - if `A` is later instantiated then `B` automatically is too, or visa-versa.

Then you go on to ask `A is (7 * (X - 2))`. Now if you have already unified `X` with `6.5` then this can be evaluated - `A` is then unified with `7 * (6.5 - 2)` or `31.5`. But remember that `A` was already unified with `B`, so `B` now also is `31.5`.

Now you say `B is (3 * (X + 4))`. So with `X` unified to `6.5` and `B` unified with `31.5` this is the same as `31.5 is (3 * (6.5 + 4))`. The right hand side is `31.5` so this is `31.5 is 31.5` which is true.

So, solving for `solve(6.5)` works.

However, if you try to solve for `X` then the first predicate works just fine. But the second one doesn't. It's like me asking "What's 7 times the number that is 2 less than the number I'm thinking of?" Unless I tell you the number I'm thinking of you can't give me an answer. The same for Prolog. It gets stuck and reports an error.