# Why won't Prolog/clpq solve this quadratic equation?

Tags: prolog, clpq

I'm using SWI-Prolog and I'm very new and still learning.  Practically speaking, this question is a follow-up to [Why can't my rule solve for X in a simple algebraic equation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649683/why-cant-my-rule-solve-for-x-in-a-simple-algebraic-equation)

I have imported clpq.

```
?- use_module(library(clpq)).
true.
```

My equation is **6x<sup>2</sup> + 7x - 3 = 0**, in which x is literally **-1.5** or also **1/3** if using the quadratic equation.

```
?- {(6 * X ^ 2) + (7 * X) - 3 = 0}.
{-3+7*X+6*X^2=0}.

?- {(6 * X ^ 2) + (7 * X) - 3 = 0}, R is float(X).
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Well, it reduced the equation slightly by changing the subtraction of **3** to the addition of **-3**, but it didn't solve for `X`.  My first step was to try giving it the answer and seeing if it accepts it.

```
?- X is -1.5, (6 * X ^ 2) + (7 * X) - 3 =:= 0.
X = -1.5.
```

Hmm... everything looks good there.  For completeness, I also ran the quadratic equations.  ("Equations" plural because I guess there's no **±** operator in Prolog.  At least, I couldn't find one.)

```
?- A is 6, B is 7, C is -3, X is (-B + sqrt((B ^ 2) - (4 * A * C))) / (2 * A).
A = 6,
B = 7,
C = -3,
X = 0.3333333333333333.

?- A is 6, B is 7, C is -3, X is (-B - sqrt((B ^ 2) - (4 * A * C))) / (2 * A).
A = 6,
B = 7,
C = -3,
X = -1.5.
```

Okay, everything seems to check out.  So, why couldn't cplq solve my equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CLPQ has limitations for non-linear constraints. For example, the non-linear constraint 6x2 + 7x - 3 = 0 can only be solved when a value for x is given, so CLPQ cannot solve quadratic or any other non-linear equations. Instead you could do:

Note that with  clpr you could solve equations like:

```
?- {9 = X^2}.
X = 3.0 ;
X = -3.0 ;
```

CLPQ would give you:

```
?- {9 = X^2}.
{9-X^2=0}.

false.
```

For quadratic equations you could do (exactly as you example):

```
 solve(X^2 + P*X + Q = 0):-
         X = -(P/2) + ((P/2)^2 - Q)^(1/2);
         X = -(P/2) - ((P/2)^2 - Q)^(1/2).
```

with CLPQ (or CLPR):

```
?- solve(X^2+2*X+1=0).
X = - (2/2)+ ((2/2)^2-1)^ (1/2) ;
X = - (2/2)- ((2/2)^2-1)^ (1/2).
```